# Is it possible "Using with alias at runtime"?

Tags: c#, using, using-directives

```
namespace
    {
    using Itest = IMyInterface
    }
```

> Then I use the Itest for rest of code But as per new requirement,
>   based on some conditions i need to set the alias at runtime. >Like
>   using Itest = {pick at runtime}

Comment: Out of interest, how could you write code against an interface which might change at runtime? It sounds a bit like you may want to implement inversion of control/dependency injection instead.

Comment: That makes no sense.  What's the use case?